# glog flag redefined error

Tags: go, kubernetes, glog

I am using glog flag log_dir in my project. Recently I imported kubernetes library and started getting this runtime panic

panic: ./aaa.test flag redefined: log_dir

```
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: goroutine 1 [running]:
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: panic(0x15ebc60, 0xc8201aae90)
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: flag.(*FlagSet).Var(0xc8200160c0, 0x7f561118c1c0, 0xc8201aae40, 0x1bddd70, 0x7, 0x1d75860, 0x2f)
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /usr/local/go/src/flag/flag.go:776 +0x454
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: flag.(*FlagSet).StringVar(0xc8200160c0, 0xc8201aae40, 0x1bddd70, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d75860, 0x2f)
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /usr/local/go/src/flag/flag.go:679 +0xc7
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: flag.(*FlagSet).String(0xc8200160c0, 0x1bddd70, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d75860, 0x2f, 0xc8201aae30)
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /usr/local/go/src/flag/flag.go:692 +0x83
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: flag.String(0x1bddd70, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1d75860, 0x2f, 0xba3950)
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /usr/local/go/src/flag/flag.go:699 +0x5f
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog.init()
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /src/ecm_infra/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/golang/glog/glog_file.go:41 +0x13e
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/labels.init()
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /src/ecm_infra/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/labels/selector.go:810 +0x6b
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned.init()
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /src/ecm_infra/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned/well_known_labels.go:30 +0x6f
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]: k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api.init()
May 16 23:51:35 ecmdev03-core01 docker[26867]:         /src/ecm_infra/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/types.go:2731 +0x64
```

It looks like glog library which is vendored by k8s is conflicting with the one that I am using. Is introducing vendor directory a solution for this problem? Should I use vendoring libraries like glide, govendor, gb etc? If yes, which one is preferred?

Answer (score 5):

That error doesn't have to do with conflicting libraries, it is a conflicting flag (`log_dir`). It means you're adding a "--log_dir" flag, and the glog library used by kubernetes also has a `log_dir` flag. This is a problem with adding flags in libraries during package init. Unfortunately vendoring won't change anything. You might be able to work around this by manipulating the `flag.CommandLine` global variable to point to a different `flag.FlagSet` when you import your log library or kubernetes, but that will be tricky since it depends on import ordering.

Comment: Note that Kubernetes just moved to a fork of glog (k8s.io/klog), in part to address some of these issues.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue when vendorizing my dependencies using glide.

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25572 kubernetes does not have a glide.lock / glide.yml, dependency flattening does not happen and in the end glog gets defined twice since vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor is also included.

The workaround from the aformentioned link worked good to me:

`glide install --strip-vendor --strip-vcs`

Answer (score 3):

I use k8s library and faced `flag redefined: log_dir` problem too.
I found several packages of kubernetes are not in my vendor.Then I `govendor add` them, then it was fixed.

I guess two copy of glog was built (one in my vendor folder, one in k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor in my $GOPATH ) when those packages are not found in my vendor folder.

How to find out missing packages? I use stupid way, rename $GOPATH/src/k8s.io to something else and build my project, see what was not found.Then add it~

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing `flag redefined: log_dir` error and the stack trace pointed `glog/glog_file.go:41 +0xd3`.

The root cause of the problem was the `GOPATH`.

I had two copies of the same repo at different locations. While trying to run tests in one of the copies, the go package was picked from the other repo. So I had two definitions of everything in `glog`.

I renamed the other repo to a new name, and then it started working.

So, please check your `GOPATH` and make sure you are not importing libraries from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

```
if flag.CommandLine.Lookup("log_dir") != nil {
    flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)
}
klog.InitFlags(nil)  // add the block above before invoking klog.InitFlags()
```

Comment: simple set `flag.CommandLine = flag.NewFlagSet(os.Args[0], flag.ExitOnError)` a new commandline with a new flag set before call flags worked for me